# How to index functions that return objects from a factory with possible additional properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to refactor my code to abstract redundant pieces to improve maintainability. I'm trying to create a single function that, depending on the parameter passed, will execute different smaller functions and return the necessary data.

For these smaller functions, they return an object whose properties come from a factory function, plus any additional properties I define that may or may not exist between all smaller functions.

```
const factoryFunc = () => ({
    func1: () => 'func1',
    func2: () => 'func2',
    func3: () => 'func3',
})

const extendedFuncs1 = () => ({
    ...factoryFunc(),
    additionalFunc1: () => 'additionalFunc1'
})

const extendedFuncs2 = () => ({
    ...factoryFunc()
})
```

I extracted the types return from these functions using the `ReturnType` utility. I wanted to get the keys for each available function, so I created a type that maps the keys to their respective function name.

```
type TExtendedFuncs1 = ReturnType<typeof extendedFuncs1>
type TExtendedFuncs2 = ReturnType<typeof extendedFuncs2>

type TFuncsTypes = {
    extendedFuncs1: keyof TExtendedFuncs1;
    extendedFuncs2: keyof TExtendedFuncs2;
}
```

Then, I created a conditional type to check if the property is of a certain function, and if it is, give the keys available for that function. The `OtherType` is for example only.

```
type TOtherTypes = {
    otherType1: string;
    otherType2: number
}

type Conditional<T = keyof (TOtherTypes & TFuncsTypes)> = T extends keyof TFuncsTypes ? {
    name: T;
    objKey: TFuncsTypes[T]
} : never
```

With this, I expected the `objKey` property to be the keys of the returned object of either `TFuncsTypes['extendedFuncs1']` or `TFuncsTypes['extendedFuncs2']`. Additionally, if it is the `TFuncsTypes['extendedFuncs1']`, the `additionalFunc1` property should exist.

```
const testFunc = (data: Conditional[]) => {
    const findData = (key: string) => data.find((d) => d.name === key);

    const res1 = extendedFuncs1()[findData('extendedFuncs1')!.objKey]
    const res2 = extendedFuncs2()[findData('extendedFuncs2')!.objKey]

    return {res1, res2}
}
```

However, typescript gives me an error for `res2`

```
Property 'additionalFunc1' does not exist on type '{ func1: () => string; func2: () => string; func3: () => string; }'
```

I am aware that it does not exist, as it is an additional property defined outside the factory, but why is it not getting evaluated to the keys defined in `TFuncsTypes['extendedFuncs2']`?

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgQ2FEAnAngMQK5mDAXhgAoBKQgPhIG8BYAKAEg5dgBGALhPIKoHIWeNnwA0DZqwBMXMpRgCpo8YOABmGT34rVS%20gF9SDBqEiwApgA8oZsABMztnHghtC3OcTpMAdL8TI0LFYyMSYEW1sASyhI8AQAGyd2DTk%20cKiYuMTWYQYDI3oTaBhLazsHJIhJN1leGnFfb38UDCSyPMN6Bih0AAczGAAVAFErG3tHVhc3ACUzKGxUMEG%20swAeHv6QOBKx8snnNgpu1aHRsonK6qI5haWV-o3V7d2LiqnJY676TYHByoeZggbi8jFK43ehy4AGszOgXiM9pcpmwANzicH7K4wuEI84Qg7AKro-QFX5DADyUAAFmZUIDgURQSAaXTAZwYNBUJEwABzEmMFm0%20mraQwMDYAC2ACM6XkyacAMLgDKxMAJNaDNyw%20E7YiDKnChkwABkQwBqwgpCoRC1mNswJ1CIt-WBAH4YKD1ZKzFxBgKQNKAFYAaThfpdQIA2oMALp5GBcMBmABucu%20xnAxWs0CSNVsCCgCC4yrs0TVCSjsc0nvERVgcB5tgAIoWEDUdVwuTzeTWC0Wmk3iMRbH3vN6BgQpzAdaQSXWs7BUEDXER7ZCiWwyFHG3ZW0XiHx14SXHxSABCbyB0Nw%20NMeswZdVNzHq7b3cttuH18fM%20X69hugd7iMudxgJ6T5sCIj5ApIeh5EAA) I made.

Comment: One more thing, what if I use the `findData` function inside another function? Will I have to make that function generic as well?

Comment: Maybe? It depends on the specifics, and is probably out of scope for this question and its comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the type `Conditional[]`, you are referring to an array of the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `Conditional` type where the type arguments take on their [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults):

```
type C = Conditional;
/* type C = {
    name: "extendedFuncs1";
    objKey: "additionalFunc1" | "func1" | "func2" | "func3";
} | {
    name: "extendedFuncs2";
    objKey: "func1" | "func2" | "func3";
} */
```

which is therefore a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type.  Your `findData` function therefore returns a value of that union type (or `undefined`), no matter what `key` is:

```
const findData = (key: string) => data.find((d) => d.name === key);

const hmm = findData("extendedFuncs2");
/* const hmm: {
name: "extendedFuncs1";
objKey: "additionalFunc1" | "func1" | "func2" | "func3";
} | {
name: "extendedFuncs2";
objKey: "func1" | "func2" | "func3";
} | undefined */
```

For all the compiler knows, then, the result will have an `objKey` property of type `"additionalFunc1"`.  And that means it will complain if you try to index into the output of `extendedFuncs2()`.

---

In order to fix this you need to express the relationship between the `key` string passed to `findData()` and the possible output type, so that the compiler understands that, for example, `findData("extendedFuncs2")?.objKey` cannot be `"additionalFunc1"`.

One way to do this is to make `findData()` generic in the type `K` of `key`, and use the [call signature for the `find()` method of arrays](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9ee093c0949b86c32120d0b5942ce05fad093a5b/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L31) that returns a narrower result if its callback is a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
interface Array<T> {
    // This is the call signature we want to use
    find<S extends T>(
        predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => value is S,
        thisArg?: any
    ): S | undefined;
}
```

Like this:

```
const findData = <K extends string>(key: K) => data.find(
    (d): d is Extract<typeof d, { name: K }> => d.name === key
);
```

Note that I have annotated the callback as a custom type guard function with the return type `d is Extract<typeof d, { name: K}>`; this lets the compiler know that a `true` result has the effect of narrowing the type of `d` from its original union type to just those members whose `name` property is of type `K`, using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter the union.

Now when we call `findData()` we will see more specific results:

```
const hmm = findData("extendedFuncs2");
/* const hmm: {
name: "extendedFuncs2";
objKey: "func1" | "func2" | "func3";
} | undefined */
```

The compiler now knows that if `objKey` exists it will be a valid key of the result of `extendedFuncs2()`, and your error goes away:

```
const res2 = extendedFuncs2()[findData('extendedFuncs2')!.objKey]; // okay
```

Depending on your use case, this might be sufficient.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgQ2FEAnAngMQK5mDAXhgAoBKQgPhIG8BYAKAEg5dgBGALhPIKoHIWeNnwA0DZqwBMXMpRgCpo8YOABmGT34rVS+gF9SDBqEiwApgA8oZsABMztnHghtC3OcTpMAdL8TI0LFYyMSYEW1sASyhI8AQAGyd2DTk+cKiYuMTWYQYDI3oTaBhLazsHJIhJN1leGnFfb38UDCSyPMN6Bih0AAczGAAVAFErG3tHVhc3ACUzKGxUMEG+swAeHv6QOBKx8snnNgpu1aHRsonK6qI5haWV-o3V7d2LiqnJY676TYHByoeZggbi8jFK43ehy4AGszOgXiM9pcpmwANzicH7K4wuEI84Qg7AKro-QFX5DADyUAAFmZUIDgURQSAaXTAZwYNBUJEwABzEmMFm0+mraQwMDYAC2ACM6XkyacAMLgDKxMAJNaDNyw+E7YiDKnChkwABkQwBqwgpCoRC1mNswJ1CIt-WBAH4YKD1ZKzFxBgKQNKAFYAaThfpdQIA2oMALp5GBcMBmABucu+xnAxWs0CSNVsCCgCC4yrs0TVCSjsc0noKjCKsDgPNsABFCwgKdzeTUdVwuTzeTWC0Wms3iMRbEPvN6BgQ5zAdaQBQ2YNTJZK3E27G2i53IrziAAie2QomSQ9L8QAegAVDAV2vJVwvQgfVxj0jTy5DwHg2H0O+6TllkSRsIeMAAD4wIeKhgZB0EqOe8Ewawqg-uIejwS+b7QSehJVOhTCBqG4YITk4FQSheBIZR2iEYwmFQbg9hbg4MA3leBTiCuW6tu2bhrCGrzjMC-Z8hQxC9jAIZDu2o52MQ4iMBOpBcLYMCRMC5yoEgUBPFsOy2CInriq+vrSTAeg2lQtjTmZhDzjq4iXt89ZZrAj7XPAzY7ggR54VcF4Cre97uau65ith5kfm8+Hnr+JEAWRQgUclwA0WlaEkjAOWWfBzFmKx6kcXWK6oECrhEAFKJkFGvG+cQfDVYcfCkAAhN4xH-vGTBlUCXnNWetX1e2jWDVUrUdV1cKxqiMBXleMAgNCCDoHW5V3GAJnlS4xk7dUejyt8t4MDy1ioP4AwAIKoDp6CalQoK8WsADKwl2MCgwSUpvTlVEwCFuZxA0ppXApiAkRGTAKYJNg5mDMZzaWEmUqyqgxnEX6VY1jD8RwxpwIvaEjCMCDEA3bybpcAgYBrUwqkwG9THlEVJKHfQHFAA)

Comment: Can you please explain what `d is Extract<typeof d, { name: K}>` does?

Comment: I have edited the answer with more info (see "Note that I have annotated...").